# Setting up static IP for sensor ethernet connection, ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager, ethernet, netplan

I need to set up an ethernet connection to a LIDAR, the steps to do so are:

Without the sensor connected to PC

```bsh
sudo ip addr add 10.5.5.1/24 dev enp12s0
```

where `enp12s0` is the name of my computers ethernet network interface, found by `ifconfig`.

Then connect the sensor and

```bsh
sudo ip link set enp12s0 up
sudo dnsmasq -C /dev/null -kd -F 10.5.5.50,10.5.5.100 -i enp12s0 --bind-dynamic
```

I was curious if I could automate this? I have tried changing the netplan `yaml` config file, as well as adding wired connection types through gnomes network interface gui. But I can't seem to get it working.

My hope is to be able to make a profile where I can click on the wired connections in gnome and select this instead of having to redo the above steps all the time. How would I go about doing this?

**Note:** this is for ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Do you use `enp12s0` for other connections as well or is it sufficient to run a configuration script when the interface is brought up?

Comment: It's the laptops main Ethernet port, I do use it for other things so I'd like to maintain the possibility. I think this is why I was drawn to the connection profiles that gnome displays in the wired connection settings.

Answer (score 0):

There may be more elegant ways to do it, but you could write a script for `NetworkManager-dispatcher` to trigger on connection change.

The dispatcher will give the interface and event as input and also sets up some convenient environment variables for you to use.

A minimal "working" example would be something like this:

`/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/<script_name>`

```
#!/bin/sh

interface="$1"
action="$2"

interfacename=enp12s0
uuid="<uuid of the desired connection>"

if [ "$action" = "up" ] && [ "$interface" = "$interfacename" ] && [ "$CONNECTION_UUID" = "$uuid" ]; then
    # Do your thing
fi
```

Obviously, you can undo any changes in a similar fashion when disabling the connection/profile.

Make sure the permissions are correct (not world-writable etc.) and that it's owned by root.

I haven't tested which events are fired when changing the wired profile, but at least changing wireless network will fire a `connectivity-change` followed by a `down` with `CONNECTION_UUID` set to the old network, followed by an `up` with `CONNECTION_UUID` set to the new network.

Comment: how do i then enable this bash script for use by the network manager? Or is this the case by default

**Edit:** Also, by "do your thing" you mean the previously mentioned lines for setting up the connection? Because some of the commands I mentioned need to be executed before the connection, so setup the port. How can this be handled here.

Comment: All you do before bringing the interface up in your question is adding an IP address to it, and that you can do to an interface that's already up. That said, there's also the `pre-up` event. The dispatcher will automatically pick up scripts in specific locations (e.g., `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/`). Check out the NetworkManager manpage for details

Comment: How can i check for the UUID or an ethernet connection?

Comment: NetworkManager stores the connections under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`. In those files you'll find the uuid of the connections.

Comment: Great, and regarding permissions. 755 is fine?

Comment: I think that should be alright, but if you can't get it to work, check the logs and see if the dispatcher complains about either permissions or something else.

Comment: By checking the logs you mean `journalctl -f -u NetworkManager` or something like this right? I've added the file, set the permissions and I can't see anything which would look like a reference to the script in the journalctl

Comment: Yes, but the brief output in `systemctl status ...` would probably do, too. I'm not sure it'll log successful execution of those scripts. Read the manual and check that the dispatcher is enabled.